# load all submodules of a package whose name conforms to some convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I am writing a package that implements a command-line tool with subcommands ("program action args..."-style).  Each subcommand is its own module within the package, and their names all adhere to the form "`s_action`" where *action* is the subcommand name.  The `__init__.py` needs to dynamically import all of these modules and pull out their argument parser and entry point.  This *seems* to be the way to do that, but it seems stupidly verbose, and the loader documentation confuses me utterly, so I'm not at all sure.

```
import pkgutil
commands = [(name[2:], finder.find_module(name).load_module(name))
            for finder, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(__path__)
            if not ispkg and name.startswith("s_")]
```

Is this actually correct?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about "better", but there's an alternative.  The [cliff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cliff/1.5.2) module makes it easy to write this sort of tool, and handles subcommands through setuptools entrypoints.  This means that not only is it easy for *you* to write subcommands...but other people can write them, too, and they get registered when the corresponding module is installed.

The [cliff documentation](https://cliff.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) includes a chunk of example code to get you started.

Comment: For this project I would prefer a stdlib-only solution, but thanks for the tip; I'll keep that in mind for future work.